# OAuth for Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth

I've been carefully reading documentation on how to implement OAuth for GAE Python here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/#Python_OAuth_and_App_Engine

The steps below make sense. But I have no idea how to make all this work. All I want to do is be able to access `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo` so that a user can store his/her email in the app's ndb.

**Step 1: import oauth**

`from google.appengine.api import oauth`

**Step 2: get current user**

`user = oauth.get_current_user()`

**Step 3: get request token**
https://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken

**Step 4: authorize token**
https://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthAuthorizeToken

**Step 5: get access token**
https://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken

**Step 6: get information from google**
'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=TOKENWOULDGOHERE

I can't find any good examples that I can use to help me solve this problem. From what I've found, it seems I always get either an import error or an authentication error. For example
`ImportError: No module named oauth2client.client`

I would be eternally grateful if anyone could write me a sample or point me in the right direction to simply grab a user's email address from OAuth2 using GAE Python. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoUdWBzUZ-M) really helped me get OAuth working. Using [decorators](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine#Decorators) simplifies the whole process.